# Lua tail-call vs loop

Tags: loops, lua, tail-call-optimization

I'm writing a little CLI module in Lua to be embedded in a C program.

I was wondering what is the best approach to handle the prompt, choosing between **tail-call** and **loop**.

As **tail-call** I would do something like this:

```
call = { help=function () print 'just ask politely' end }

function shell ()
  io.write ('% ')
  local cmd = io.read ()

  if cmd ~= 'quit' then      
    call[cmd] () -- for simplicity assume call[cmd] is never nil
    return shell ()
  end
end
```

I would ask the following questions:

1. Is it a correct use/implementation of *tail-call elimination*? Does `call[cmd] ()` introduce any disturbance in the stack, so that I won't take advantage of the *tail-call elimination*?
2. Is it better using a **loop** like the following? If yes, why?

   ```
   repeat
     io.write ('% ')
     local cmd = io.read()

     -- do stuff
   until cmd == 'quit'
   ```
3. In Programming in Lua is stated

   > A *tail call* is a goto dressed as a call.

   so is there any concrete difference between a tail call and a loop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it a correct use/implementation of tail-call elimination?

If you're asking if the call to `shell` at the end is a proper tail call according to Lua syntax, [the answer is yes](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8).

> Does call[cmd] () introduce any disturbance in the stack, so that I won't take advantage of the tail-call elimination?

A function call does not modify the stack in the manner in which you're thinking. In Lua, the *only* requirement of a tail call is that it be of the form `return Function(params)`, with no extra return values that aren't the return values from the function.

A proper tail call does not even have to call itself; it doesn't need to be recursive.

> Is it better using a loop like the following? If yes, why?

That's a subjective point. Personally, I'd say that the loop is more clear on what's going on.

However, if you want an objective question of performance, consider this: the tail call will never be *faster* than the loop. The absolute best you're going to get in terms of performance is equal.

And it probably won't be that. Lua tail call "optimization" simply means that it reuses the stack entries of the current function. Lua still has to fetch the function from the global table. Lua still has to do all of the overhead of calling a function; it just doesn't have to allocate more stack memory.

It's really about not overflowing the stack and not allocating memory when it's unnecessary.

> is there any concrete difference between a tail call and a loop?

See above.

Comment: You explain more clearly what I meant. +1 and removed my answer.

Comment: So in many cases, a tail recursive function could be slower in Lua than a looping function. But consider the case of needing to process varargs, or multiple return values. `function recurse(n, i, sum, val, ...)
 if n == i then return i + sum end
 return recurse(n, i+1, sum+val, ...)
end` Call this as `recurse(n, 1, ...)` In vanilla Lua, this is a little bit slower than looping over a table, but don't forget you'd have to create, initialize, and collect that table when you're done, every time. In LuaJIT, this code is actually a couple *orders of magnitude* faster than looping over an array.

Comment: Sorry, should be: `if n == i then return val + sum end`.

Comment: Since this is about cli, the bottleneck is probably the user and not the loop or tail-call mechanics.